# Passing values from Express NodeJS to AngularJS controller variable

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, express

I am trying to pass some values from express NodeJS server to AngularJS controller variable. Here is the code snippet....

Server

```
app.post('/run-engine', function(req, res){
  console.log(req)

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

  fs.readFile('index.html', 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
        res.end('error occurred');
        return;
    }
    var reconData = 'some temp';  //here I assign temp variable with needed value

    var renderedHtml = ejs.render(content, {data: reconData})
    res.end(renderedHtml);
  });

});
```

HTML code snippet

```
<section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel tab2" id="scroll-tab-2">
  <div class="page-content">
    <h1>This is Tab2</h1> Data: <%= data %>
    <form method='post' action='run-engine' enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type='file' name='fileUploaded'></input>
      <input type='submit'></input>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

In the html page, I could see the value of "reconData" (which is rendered by 'data' in the content from server post method).

I want the same 'reconData' to be assigned as scope variable (engineData) in angularjs controller but I am unable to do so... 
Angular js controller code snippet

```
var myApp1 = angular.module('msnapp',[]);
myApp1.controller("MsnController", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.engineData = ?? //this needs to be equal to reconData from server side
});
```

How do I get the engineData to be assigned as 'reconData' from server?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var myApp1 = angular.module('msnapp',[]);
myApp1.controller("MsnController", function($scope, $http) {

    $http({ method: 'POST',
            url: '/run-engine'
         }).then(function (response){
            $scope.engineData = response.data;
         }, function (error) {});

});
```

Comment: 'response' is entire html body

Comment: @Jay Yeah it is. I updated it to pull just the data ... like the docs say [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: But how can I get only 'reconData' so that I can use the value into the html page. I need to bind the value into angular controller variable. The html body is used that variable. As I show, in HTML I can use the value of reconData directly (through 'data' variable) but I need it in angular controller.

Comment: Sorry, I did not check response.data part. In that case I am getting undefined.

Comment: Any solution to this problem??

Comment: Dude just send it! Create another path in your express server that responds with `res.json(reconData)` instead of the compiled HTML.